# Remove whitespaces in a function name before and after parentheses, even in arguments

Tags: javascript, regex

I am just a noob when it comes to regex in JavaScript,
I wanted to remove white-spaces everywhere in a function before and after parentheses with any number of arguments, even between arguments.

```
eg: function_name      (     arguments1,    argument   2,   argument3    );
```

converts to `function_name(argument1,argument2,argument3);`

Answer (score 4):

You can remove white-spaces from everywhere,
just look it like a string, not a function with parentheses
Try

```
'function_name      (     arguments1,    argument   2,   argument3    );'.replace(/\s/g,'');
```

or

```
'function_name      (     arguments1,    argument   2,   argument3    );'.replace(/\s+/g,'');
```

Note: you can take any number of arguments here, I'm just taking your example